# Android IME: How to attach an edittext to the IME?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am wondering how will I be able to add an Edittext to the keyboard layout. This Edittext should be just above the input_view of the keyboard, just like we have a candidate view. Whenever, the user wants to type something the input should first go to this Edittext, and later to the view in focus.

I am wondering what should be the approach in doing this. I was trying to attach this Edittext, just like we have ExtractEditText in full screen mode, but manipulating or forcing the ExtractEditText to appear always didn't seem fruitful for me!

I really got stuck, and any help to provide me a little direction would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a whole lot of people who have played in IMEs before, and the ones who have don't necessarily share information. Ever. It's just the nature of the beast.

I will say, having worked on an IME and tried to do what you're trying to do, you're in for a world of hurt. IMEs simply don't work that way. By the time you're actually focused on the `EditText` you are trying to focus, you're in a different context of IME. It's fairly mindblowing the things that you'll experience while trying to get it to work. And, at the end of the day, you won't be any closer.

I'd strongly urge you to abandon the effort. Design a different way. You will lead a much happier life.